# Shiny-server configuration not working properly

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to set up a shiny server, where i want to display my shiny application, i have a configuration file, that looks like this.

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }

  location /app {

    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/role-mining-app;

 }
}
```

the idea, is that i want to serve my application under the url `{url}:{port}/app` initially, but it fails to load, with these configurations

i have checked that the directory path both serves a `server.r` and a `ui.r` file, and i have checked that the project can run in R-studio correctly.